# The built-in variable "barstate.isconfirmed" don't work as intended

Tags: pine-script

as i said in the title, i'm trying to use barstate.isconfirmed to know when a green candle appear.

`Vert = (fast>slow)`

`ClosedBarGreen= barstate.isconfirmed and (close>open)`

`strategy.order("buy",true,when = ClosedBarGreen and Vert)`

But it's not working at all:

[PineScript Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXNvD.png)

Deeply thank you all for any help.
Have a good day.

Comment: Orders are executed on the following bar. Your code does exactly as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

try
ClosedBarGreen= barstate.isconfirmed and (close>open) and (close>close[1])

Answer (score 0):

As @rumpypumpydumpy said, by default your strategy orders are executed on the start of a next bar. If you want your order to be placed at the close of the bar then you need to check the box (recalculate on bar close) under the properties tab of your strategy configuration. Alternatively, you can also specify that in the code with a parameter to the strategy called `process_order_on_close=true`.